# Prevent duplicate username from federated logins

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I have Cognito setup with login supported from multiple identity providers (Cognito User Pools, Facebook, and Google). In my User Pool configuration I have email used as username. The desired functionality is to have username be unique across all identity providers. i.e. if a user logs in with Facebook and their facebook email is "user@test.com" and then they login with Google and their google email is "user@test.com", either they should not be able to login or their federated identities should be merged.

This is user management for connected devices. I don't want a user to setup a few devices while logged into Facebook, then login with Google and not be able to see their devices from their Facebook account.

I know this gets complicated since you can create a Facebook account with just a phone number.

I know there is a pre-authentication trigger in Cognito User Pool's, but it doesn't seem to be triggering when I login with a federated identity. Is there a trigger than I can use that will fire no matter which identity provider I use (User Pool, Facebook, Google)?

Thanks,

Comment: Any update on this Brother ?

Comment: is there anybody to answer this please

Comment: Try a workaround with a prefly upsertion handle on a trigger or server-side like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635482/aws-cognito-best-practice-to-handle-same-user-with-same-email-address-signing