# AWS Cognito. One account from email

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, oauth, amazon-cognito

I decided to use AWS Cognito for sign in/sign up in my app but I have one problem. If user login via email, Facebook and google, user will have 3 different accounts. But I want to bind this three accounts by email, for example if user login with google, user can login Facebook or login with email by forgot password.

Comment: you found any solution without help of lambda hook ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Cognito: Best practice to handle same user (with same email address) signing in from different identity providers (Google, Facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635482/aws-cognito-best-practice-to-handle-same-user-with-same-email-address-signing)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Link Provider to merge 3 accounts, there is a thread for this, hope this help you: [AWS Cognito: Best practice to handle same user (with same email address) signing in from different identity providers (Google, Facebook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59635482/aws-cognito-best-practice-to-handle-same-user-with-same-email-address-signing/59642140#59642140)